# stopPropagation without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I bind to a link (by using the `.live()` function of jQuery) `click` event and then manually add an `onclick` event handler with pure JS and HTML (like `<a href="".... onclick="some action">`). I want to prevent bubbling of the event to the `live` method but I don't know how.

Maybe `e.stopPropagation()` is helpful in this situation but the event handler added with `onclick` is written in pure JS and I can't call `stopPropagation()` from outside the jQuery element wrapper. `return false` in this situation does not work. I tried to substitute `return false` with `$.Event('click').stopPropagation()` but I think this is wrong as it did not work.

How to prevent bubling to `live()` method without jQuery wrapper?

Comment: `return false` should do the trick. It should work if you do: `<a href="".... onclick="some action; return false;">` . Btw. `event.stopPropagation()` is not a jQuery method. The problem is that IE uses a different event modle that does not offer this method, so `return`ing `false` is the best solution ins this case. The question is, why do you use inline event handlers at all?

Comment: return false not cancel event that bind by .live

Comment: return false within a jQuery function is not the same as outside of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: @Mrchief: I see thanks.... I always thought it was....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/), you cannot stop propagation. This is because with `.live`, the event handler is bound to the root of the DOM tree. Hence the event must bubble upto the highest element before your handler can be called. Its one of the caveats on using `.live`.

Consider using [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (if you want the handler to persist) or use [.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) instead.

If you want the live handler to be disabled completly, use die:

```
$("#myHref").die("click", aClick); // this will remove any existing event handlers
$("#myHref").click(yourhandler);   // add your handler
```

[Demo 1: JsFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/VtJyg/1/)

Or, add an inline handler (and cancel the event from there):

```
<a href=".." onclick="yourhandler">
```

[Demo 2: JsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/VtJyg/26/)

Inline handlers will be called first always before any jquery event handlers.

Comment: I can't change code that bind by .live. There are no way to fix this?

Comment: But it is possible to stop the event from another event handler that is bound to the element.

Comment: Only if that event handler is registered first. jQuery will queue them up, right?

Comment: @Mrchief: As you said yourself, `live` binds the event handler to the root. Every event handler bound *directly to the element* can stop the event from bubbling up to the root.

Comment: @Abonec: See my updated answers and fiddle. Hopefully you can use one of them.

Comment: Thx, it works for ff and chrome. I haven't posibility to test it in IE today, but thanx.

Comment: Hah... It's work fine in Chromium and IE but not working in firefox. Firefox can't find event object.

Comment: Oh tnx. It's work perfectly in my browsers(ff,ie8,chrome and opera). Thx you!

Comment: **with·out**
/wəˈT͟Hao͝ot,wəˈTHout/
*preposition*
1. in the absence of.

Answer (score 15):

I was under the assumption that `return false` in "normal" event handlers prevents the event from bubbling as well, [but I was wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) (thanks [@Mrchief](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244353/mrchief)).

There are other ways to stop it though, as described on [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html):

```
function doSomething(e)
{
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

`cancelBubble` is for IE, `stopPropagation` works in all W3C compatible browsers.

Comment: When I trying get any information about event (onclick"alert(window.event)") it show me alert "undefined" when i click.

Comment: @Abonec: `window.event` is only available in IE (and Chrome). In other browsers, the event object is passed to the event handler as parameter.

Comment: but i don't use function and cant give paramenetr (e).

Comment: @Abonec: If you have an inline event handler, then the event object is available via the variable `event` or via `window.event`. E.g. `onclick="event = event || window.event; event.cancelBubble = true; //etc...."`. Or you defined a function and call `onclick="something(event||window.event)"`.

Comment: Thx you. I newbie in js and some js structures is difficult for me, your last comment is very useful for me.

Comment: @Abonec: In general I can recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) and regarding event handling, have a look at the [quirksmode.org articles](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). If you read trough both, you have a very good basis.