# How to put checkbox in front of clickable row

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I was making a mailing sort of system.Now am stuck with a problem :

Suppose i have rows in table showing inbox messages and on click they show full message.Now with each row i want to have a checkbox,so that on checking that checkbox i can delete that particular row from the page.But as i had made whole row clickable,as soon as i check the checkbox it moves on to next page.

My code is something like this  :

```
<tr bgcolor="#5D1B90" color="#FFFFFF" onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true,false);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false,false);" onclick="DoNav('showmail.jsp?mid=<%=messageid%>');">    
<td callspan="3"><%=sendername%>  :   <%=messagesubject%>      <%=sendingtime%></td>
</tr>
```

Here onNav function is :

```
function DoNav(theUrl)
{
   document.location.href = theUrl;
}
```

So how to make it work according to requirement?

Also i want sendingtime of each row to be right aligned and subject to be center aligned in row.How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop your `checkbox` click propagate to the parent `TR`

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

<sub>Also, you cannot have nothing *in-front* of a `tr` element but another `tr` element. Put your checkbox inside an `tr` inner `td` element.
You also have a typo in your HTML `callspan :) should be **colspan**`</sub>

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/kolaju/3/edit)

```
<td colspan="3">John  :   "Hello"      10:00</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="DoRemove(event);"></td>
```

JS:

```
function DoNav(theUrl){
   document.location.href = theUrl;
}
function DoRemove(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    // Remove code here.
}
```

[stopPropagation without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095826/stoppropagation-without-jquery)

Comment: And how to increase the length of each row of the table and also what if i want this 10:00 to extreme right and "Hello" in the middle of row?

Comment: @user3462609 what you mean by *increase length of each row?* (Use CSS to position your elements as needed, I hope the above answers your question)